# resolving boundary condition hyperbola function.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

how 
$ y = C \cosh x + D \sinh x -ax $
evaluated at boundary condition x = 0 and x = 1
becomes this

$ y = ({a+B}/{ \sinh 1}) \sinh x -ax   $

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you will need the value of $y$ as well for conditions $x = 0$ and $y = 0$. What are those conditions?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh I presume you mean $x=0$ and $x=1$?

Comment: Yes. I meant that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are given boundary conditions for $y(x)$ as follows: $y(0)=0$ and $y(1)=B$. Then your function is $$y(x)=C\cosh x+D\sinh x-ax$$
$$y(0)=0\implies 0=C\cosh(0)+D\sinh(0)-0=C$$ So $C=0$. Then $$y(1)=B\implies B=D\sinh1-a$$So $ D=\frac{a+B}{\sinh1}$.
This gives $$y(x)=\frac{a+B}{\sinh1}\sinh x-ax$$